Ubuntu Server 22.04 Replace Failed SSD in mdadm RAID1 Boot Disk
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server that has its boot disk on a mdadm RAID1 array consisting of two 240 GB SSDs (/dev/sda & /dev/sdb). This mdadm array was setup using curtin during the initial install. In addition only the boot, root & swap file systems are on this array - all other files are on a ZFS RAID10 array.
One of the disks (/dev/sda) has now failed completely and needs to be replaced. While the system continues to run on the other disk (/dev/sdb), it will only boot on the failed disk (/dev/sda). This presents somewhat of a problem since I will need to reboot the system on /dev/sdb after I have shutdown the system and replaced /dev/sda. Both /dev/sda & /dev/sdb have up to date EFI & /boot partitions.
I am currently planning the replacement and would appreciate any advice. So far, I think I will need to do the following:

mark the partitions as failed using mdadm
remove the failed partitions from the array using mdadm
set /dev/sdb to be the boot disk
shutdown the system
physically remove the failed disk and replace it with a new disk
restart the system
partition the new disk using sfdisk
add the new partitions to the existing arrays using mdadm
copy the files from the EFI partition to the new disk
update grub

Most of the process looks pretty straight forward. It is the step 3 and 10 that deal with booting that I am not sure about.
Below are the details of my setup:
fdisk /dev/sdb (both disk are partitioned the same)
Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048   2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/sdb2   2203648   4300799   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3   4300800  71409663  67108864    32G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb4  71409664 468858879 397449216 189.5G Linux filesystem

cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md125 : active raid1 sdb4[0] sda4[1](F)
      198592512 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 2/2 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0](F)
      33520640 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      
md127 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sda2[2](F)
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/md125p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-7f83998a:b81f586c:e3e6497a:9a9e36ce-part1 / ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-56619c5a:2fc620ba:3642eeae:73fd6319-part1 none swap sw 0 0
# /boot was on /dev/md127p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-78148d71:a0c26fd8:9ee89f4c:bfa69120-part1 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/D72E-12F9 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1

lsblk
├─sda1          8:1    0     1G  0 part  
├─sda2          8:2    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md127       9:127  0  1022M  0 raid1 
│   └─md127p1 259:1    0  1020M  0 part  /boot
├─sda3          8:3    0    32G  0 part  
│ └─md126       9:126  0    32G  0 raid1 
│   └─md126p1 259:0    0    32G  0 part  [SWAP]
└─sda4          8:4    0 189.5G  0 part  
  └─md125       9:125  0 189.4G  0 raid1 
    └─md125p1 259:2    0 189.4G  0 part  /
sdb             8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sdb2          8:18   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md127       9:127  0  1022M  0 raid1 
│   └─md127p1 259:1    0  1020M  0 part  /boot
├─sdb3          8:19   0    32G  0 part  
│ └─md126       9:126  0    32G  0 raid1 
│   └─md126p1 259:0    0    32G  0 part  [SWAP]
└─sdb4          8:20   0 189.5G  0 part  
  └─md125       9:125  0 189.4G  0 raid1 
    └─md125p1 259:2    0 189.4G  0 part  /

